# Why momentjs is give wrong results

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i have this code in moment.js.its work well,but i have one question.Example,today date is 06/01/2021 and with value 06/01/2021 of start DIV it give me result 0,same if i set 07-01-2021,it give me result of 0 .But if i set 08-01-2021 ,then it give me 1 (must be 2).i think if i set tomorrow date (07-01-2021) i must return value of 1,but i receive 0,,,why? is there a way to receive 1? thank you for explain and help me.

MY HTML

```
<div id="start">07-01-2021</div>
<div id='result'></div>
```

javascript,monent.js

```
var inputDiv = document.getElementById('start');
var startDate = moment();
var endDate = moment(inputDiv.innerHTML, "DD/MM/YYYY");
var result = 'Diff: ' + endDate.diff(startDate, 'days');
$('#result').html(result);
```

Comment: Quick guess, one date is in UTC and the other is in local (or *converted* to UTC/local from local/UTC) and the difference from the timezones makes it a day less than it would otherwise be. Not sure though, but I'm always sketchy about dealing with datetimes with no timezone info attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moment is going to work as a datetime, so both of your dates are going to have a time associated with them.

```
var inputDiv = document.getElementById('start');
var endDate = moment(inputDiv.innerHTML, "DD/MM/YYYY"); // time of midnight (start of day), locally
var startDate = moment();  // time you run the code
```

So, `endDate.diff(startDate, 'days')` is going to calculate something akin to `(tonight at midnight[locally]) - (today, midday[locally])`.  There is no full day difference in that equation.

Try either `endDate.endOf('day').diff(startDate, 'days')`, or better yet `endDate.endOf('day').diff(startDate.endOf('day'), 'days')`.

Or you could just set `var startDate = moment().startOf('day');` and use the code you have now.

Comment: I was try it with your advices,but it give me error,could you please write full code ,cos im not sure i put your code in right place.thanks

Comment: Try again.  You are using `endDate` and `startDate`, and I wrote it with `end` and `start`.  The response above has been update, give it another go.

Comment: One more questio,.is it possible to add IF statement to result?example IF result is equal to 2,then do something,else if result ==3 then other thing,,is it possible?

Comment: Well, sure, man.  Assign your diff to a variable and if/else off of that variable.  I can't do multi-line responses in comments, so this will be a long response, but try `var dayDiff = endDate.endOf('day').diff(startDate.endOf('day'), 'days'); if (dayDiff === 2 ) { /* do something */ } else if (dayDiff === 3) { /* do other thing */ } else { /* do a fallback thing */ }`.  If you need more than this, feel free to create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try "DD-MM-YYYY" instead of "DD/MM/YYYY"